# Estou com dificuldades no ajax para voltar

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Para ficar bem explicado.. estou começando agora no mundo do js e ajax..

estou fazendo um codigo que criar options de horarios disponivel quando clicar no botão.. tudo funciona normal em strings ("1/2/3/4/5"), mas quando está em string na variavel $_POST['name'] //recebe a data que o cliente escolheu da error ao retornar dados do mysqli_query

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
<input type="date"   id=valor >
<p id="valorDigitado"></p>
```

AJAX.JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#form_consulta').submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var capturando = "";
    
    capturando = document.getElementById('valor').value;
    var resultado2 = capturando.substring(8, 15);


        var form4 = "";
        $.ajax({
            url:"php/consulta_horario.php",
            method:"POST",
            type:"POST",
            data:form4, 
            success: function(return_consulta) { 
                $( "#resp_consulta" ).html( return_consulta );

            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Erro ao achar caminho do arquivo");
            }
        }); 

        
        $.ajax({
    url: "php/consulta_horario.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: resultado2,
    },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log("Resultado:" + resultado2);
    }
});

    });



});
```

CONSULTAHORARIO.php

```
<?php
    $usuario = $_POST['name']; // Quando troco o POST por "1" ou "2" por exemplo o select funciona, mas quando coloco o post volta o error
    include_once("conexao.php");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM horario WHERE id = ".$usuario;
$resultado = mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("<option>Erro ao retornar dados</option>");

 //Obtendo os dados por meio de um loop while
 while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
 {
    echo $_POST['name'];
    if ($registro['6'] >= "1") {
        echo "<option>6:00</option>";
    }
    if ($registro['6:30'] >= "1") {
        echo "<option>6:30</option>";
    }
}  

?>
```

Comment: Coloque o erro que recebe...

Answer (score 0):

Olhando o seu código tem 2 coisas que eu consegui observar:

1 -  aqui você está atribuindo um id sem `""`, então deve ficar assim:

```
<input type="date"   id="valor">
```

2 - no seu ajax o parametro data está indo com valor inválido, você precisa sempre trabalhar o data como um objeto de chave e valor, no seu PHP eu vi que está aguardando o parâmetro `name`, mas no ajax você não está enviando ele, logo o seu código ajax deve ficar assim:

```
var form4 = "";
        $.ajax({
            url:"php/consulta_horario.php",
            method:"POST",
            type:"POST",
            data:{ name: form4 }, 
            success: function(return_consulta) { 
                $( "#resp_consulta" ).html( return_consulta );

            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Erro ao achar caminho do arquivo");
            }
        });
```

Isso é o que eu consegui ver no seu código, mas se você puder postar a mensagem de erro que você recebe, e também se existe algum erro sendo exibido no console do seu navegador. Isso ajudaria muito em um diagnóstico mais acertivo.

Espero ter ajudado!